# How do I do an graphql axios call to supabase to

Tags: rest, axios, graphql, supabase

I try to do an axios call to graphql in the documentation i see:

```
curl -X POST https://<PROJECT_REF>.supabase.co/graphql/v1 \
    -H 'apiKey: <API_KEY>'\
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-raw '
    {
      "query":"{ accountCollection(first: 3) { edges { node { id } } } }"
    }'
```

I am transforming that to a axios call like that:

```
var callObject = {
   url:https://<PROJECT_REF>.supabase.co/graphql/v1,
   method:"POST",
   headers:{
      "Authorization" : "Bearer " + apiKey,
      "apikey": apiKey,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
   }
}
var response = await axios(callObject)
```

Now I tried many things to add the --data-raw payload into the call. But i couldn't find the solution. It always shows me a 404

How can handle that?

Comment: Are you exposing [graphql settings](https://app.supabase.com/project/_/settings/api)? Did you also make sure the extension pg_graphql is [enabled](https://app.supabase.com/project/_/database/extensions)?

Also, if you are using the anon key, check if you have RLS enabled for the tables.

Comment: Yes I exposed that and enabled the pg_graphql. Also I toke care of the RLS. But i don't know how to pass the query into the axios call

Answer (score 0):

Your Axios request is missing the query, try this, similar worked for me (abc123ff22 as the project ref, apikey is the API key, accesstoken is the access token, don't use apikey):

```
const axios = require('axios')
const url = 'https://adsfvutfdffylp.supabase.co/graphql/v1'
const apikey =
  'apikey'
let data = JSON.stringify({
  query: 'query { tenantsCollection(first: 3) { edges { node { id } } } }',
})

let config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: url,
  headers: {
    apiKey: apikey,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  data: data,
}

axios
  .request(config)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

The code above came from a Postman Export

Edit: verified that the above works